# What is the song that plays 15 seconds before episode 56 fairy tail?

Tags: fairy-tail

What is the song that plays 15 seconds before episode 56 fairy tail?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TEZ7YHC1kYk

Answer (score 1):

So it took me a fat minute to figure out what this song was, due to it being NOWHERE on youtube due to ContentID copyrights. The places it used to be have all been taken down. You can still find covers of the song there.

EN Name: Alliance Force, Assemble!

JP Name: Rengougun Shuuketsu

Soundcloud original for download: https://soundcloud.com/nafisa-akter/rengougun-shuuketsu-ost

Cover Remix Pianos on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDFQBC0bmRs